# How would you create a loop with 2 interacting variables using deepcopy

Tags: python, loops, neural-network

[In this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iPyBZ.jpg)I have two variables that depend on each other. One, "K" is the result of a concatenation betweeen a certain vector "noise" and a one hot pixel encoding "new", while noise at time step two is the result of foward propagating K from a previous times step, and different "news" accompany this progression(as in the different pixels in sequence from an image). My problem is that copy.deepcopy doesn't seem to separate the two instances of noise

I tried putting indexes on the different noise's and adding new dimensions into it first before updating the index and then deep copying...didn't work. it seems that the value of noise depends only on the interaction between the new at hand and the zero noise vector concatenated and Forward Propagated.I'm testing it on MNIST csv and most of the first csv values are zero, at some points the value changes drastically as with a different one hot encoding corresponding to darker pixels, then when the zero's return it goes back to the original value it had...i am expecting it to accumulate information , and not have no recollection of past pixel values.

```
for x,y in a.items():
     indexo = []
     indexo.append(y)

     indexo = np.asarray(indexo)
     new = np.zeros((z,aaa))
     new[np.arange(z), indexo] = 1
     new=np.ndarray.flatten(new)
     voo=np.concatenate((voo,vii))
     vg[newo_index]=copy.deepcopy(new)





     print(noise.shape)
     print(noise[noise_index])


     k=np.concatenate((noise[noise_index],vg[newo_index]),axis=0)
     noise=np.concatenate((noise,np.zeros((1,4))))
     print(noise.shape)
     noise_index+=1

     k=k.reshape((1,260,1))

     noise[noise_index]=copy.deepcopy(model1.predict(k))
     print(noise[noise_index])
```

> ```
> (3, 4)
> [0. 0. 0. 0.]
> (4, 4)
> [0.02567281 0.40914842 0.22369435 0.08106659]
> (4, 4)
> [0.02567281 0.40914842 0.22369435 0.08106659]
> (5, 4)
> [0.02619855 0.40627998 0.2288992  0.08426424]
> (5, 4)
> [0.02619855 0.40627998 0.2288992  0.08426424]
> (6, 4)
> [0.02620577 0.40642107 0.22897767 0.08420368]
> (6, 4)
> [0.02620577 0.40642107 0.22897767 0.08420368]
> ```

Answer (score 0):

i found the problem...with certain functions if you feed the output back into the function repeatedly the output converges to a defined number...the function that was causing my problems was the sigmoid